# foundation interchange callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm trying to use the callback of interchange plugin. This is my code:

```
$('#project_slideshow').on('replace', 'img', function (e, new_path, original_path) {
   $(e.currentTarget).load(function () {
     console.log($(this).width());
   })
});
```

The problem here is that when I resize the window the parsed elements are every time more and more.

I'm also trying to understand if there is a way to use this callback to send back custom values like the media query it is currently using.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think what you meant to use was `.on('load')`, as `load` actually loads data from the server:

http://api.jquery.com/load/

```
$('#project_slideshow').on('replace', 'img', function (e, new_path, original_path) {
   $(e.currentTarget).on('load', function () {
     console.log($(this).width());
   })
});
```

You can use `window.matchMedia` method to detect the current media query, [article here](http://tylergaw.com/articles/reacting-to-media-queries-in-javascript)